# how to fix error java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

the following code which is given below this giving me error( java.util.NoSuchElementException) how to fix it

- Gets the String that follows the line that starts with the given String.
- Gets and returns the String on the very next line.
- If the given String doesn't exist, should return null.
- 
- Example(s):
- - If an ArrayList lines contains: "hello" and "world", and we call getNextStringStartsWith("hello"), we'll get the String "world".
- - If an ArrayList lines contains: "Course" and "CIT590", and we call getNextStringStartsWith("Course"), we'll get the String "CIT590".
- - If an ArrayList lines contains: "hello" and "world", and we call getNextStringStartsWith("goodbye"), we'll get null.

    ```
    string getNextStringStartsWith(String str) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = lines.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext() && !iterator.next().equals(str)) {
        iterator.next();
    }
    if(iterator.hasNext()){
        return iterator.next();
    }else{

        return null;
    }
    ```

    }

Comment: Why are you calling `next()` again inside the loop?

Comment: Your understanding of `next()` is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't actually understand the logic that you are trying to implement, but below could be your code, if you want to search a `str` in `lines`, and return `str` if found, else `null`:

```
String getNextStringStartsWith(String str) {
      // TODO Implement method
      Iterator<String> iterator = lines.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          String data = iterator.next();
          if (str.equals(data)) {
             return data
          }
       }
       return null
}
```

Edit 1: As I understand, you want to get the word after `str` if the `lines` has `str`

```
String getNextStringStartsWith(String str) {
      // TODO Implement method
      Iterator<String> iterator = lines.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          String data = iterator.next();
          // check if the current element is string and next 
          // element exists, if so return next element. Else 
          // continue and return null after loop
          if (str.equals(data) && iterator.hasNext()) {
             return iterator.next();
          }
       }
       return null
}
```

Hope this helps !